# I need to create a custom tree data-structure using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, data-structures, tree

I looked up this basic format for a tree structure in javascript:

```
function Tree(parent, child, data) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.children = child || [];
    this.data = data;
    this.addNode ...
    this.addChild ...
}
```

the problem I have is making a tree that is "long" with this. The data I'm using is a list of streets on a trail that is almost one straight path, but there are a couple of small splits in the trail, the data would look something like:

```
A -> 
B -> 
C -> 
D -> E,F   
E -> 
G -> 
H    
F -> I  
I -> J  
J -> K,L   
K ->
M -> 
N
L -> O
O -> P
```

I'd like to avoid code that looks like:

```
tree.children[0].children[0].children[0].addNode("E");
tree.children[0].children[0].children[0].push("F");
```

so one of my questions is how to traverse the tree, simply by saying?

```
node = tree;
while(node.children != null)
    node = node.children[0];
```

if you could help me out, I'd appreciate it, thanks,

mathacka

Comment: Have you tried your code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most managable approach for this structure is IMHO to use linked lists.

```
function Node(parentNode)
{
    this.Parent=parentNode;
    this.FirstChild=null;
    this.LastChild=null;
    this.PreviousSibling=null;
    this.NextSibling=null;
}
Node.prototype.AddChild=function(child)
{
    child.Parent = this;
    child.PreviousSibling = this.LastChild;
    if (this.LastChild != null)
        this.LastChild.NextSibling = child;
    this.LastChild = child;
    if (this.FirstChild == null)
        this.FirstChild = child;
}
```

To loop through children, do something like this:

```
function GetChildren(node)
{
    var result=new Array();
    var child=node.FirstChild;
    while(child)
    {
        result.push(child);
        child=child.NextSibling;
    }
    return result;
}
```

(edit) The "Node"-object is just an example and it should have meaningful properties added to it. Using this as a base for all objects in your tree, it may have any depth without making it more complex. You can add more functions, like GetChildByName, RemoveChild, and so on.

Comment: I realize I could put 2 children in a linked list, do you have any suggestions on how to traverse a multi-child list?

Comment: The code above would let you traverse unlimited number of children. Each child could have unlimited number of grand children, and so on. Try it out. The code pattern is called Linked List.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var Tree = function () {
    Tree.obj = {};
    return Tree;
};

// Parent Will be object
Tree.AddChild = function (parent, child) {

    if (parent === null) {
        if (Tree.obj.hasOwnProperty(child)) {
            return Tree.obj[child];
        } else {
            Tree.obj[child] = {};
            return Tree.obj[child];
        }
    } else {
        parent[child] = {};
        return parent[child];
    }
};


// Uses

// Inserting - 
var t = Tree();
var twoDoor = t.AddChild(null, "2 Door");
var fdoor = t.AddChild(null, "4 Door");
t.AddChild(fdoor, "manual");
t.AddChild(twoDoor, "automatic");
var man = t.AddChild(twoDoor, "manual");
t.AddChild(man, "Extended Cab");
console.log(t.obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this approach on how to create tree structures from SQL queries:

http://blog.tcs.de/creating-trees-from-sql-queries-in-javascript/

Comment: Could you add a description of how the linked approach solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some calculation at every node in the tree then you could add a `traverse` function to your tree nodes, something like:

```
Tree.prototype.traverse = function( operation ){
    // call the operation function and pass in the current node
    operation( this )

    // call traverse on every child of this node
    for( var i=0; i<this.children.length; i++ )
        this.children[i].traverse( operation )
}

// an example operation that finds all the leaf nodes
var leaves = []
myTree.traverse( function( node ){
    if( !node.children.length )
        leaves.push(node)
}
```

Alternatively if you're doing something more specific such as manipulating the tree or finding a particular node then you may want to look at the [Visitor Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: thank you, I did find this as well http://www.drdobbs.com/database/ternary-search-trees/184410528